# Securing a password by verifying encrypted random string

Tags: .net, encryption, passwords

I want to make an application that saves some encrypted configuration data in a XML file. The idea is that I want the user to set a password and with it to encrypt my data.

If I have the password: 'mypass' and the data: 'mydata'.
When a user defines the password, my app will generate a random string:'myRandomString'. In my XML file I will save:

- 'myRandomString'
- 'f6354a1eb2a1deb2' -witch is  'myRandomString' encrypted
  with 'mypass'
- '69380d137534519' -witch is  'mydata' encrypted
  with 'mypass'

When the users logs in, I will compare 'myRandomString' with the decrypted version of 'f6354a1eb2a1deb2'. If they are equal then my pass is OK and I can decrypt 'mydata'.

From [AES key finding from encrypted and plaintext data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236835/aes-key-finding-from-encrypted-and-plaintext-data) I know that this method is prety secure but I want to know if there are better methods to secure the password withouth using 'Protected Configuration'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead use an HMAC in this scenario.  It is a keyed-hash function.

Even if the random string has not been modified, you cannot assume that the password hasn't either.

Using an HMAC you can be aware of any changes made to the entire file since it was created by your application.

Build your XML file with the encrypted fields, feed it through an HMAC and then append the result.  You can do the same when you use the file again and if the HMACs aren't equal, the file has been changed.

It wouldn't hurt to use a time-safe comparison for checking the HMACs

Comment: Question: SInce the comparison is comparing a hash and a single bit change in the input produces approximately 50% of the output bits to change why is a time-safe comparison necessary?

Comment: @zaph Because an attacker could modify the HMAC that has been appended until it matches the HMAC of the input data they have changed, using a timing attack. Theoretically.

Comment: I will think about that, I assume you are far more versed in crypto analysis than me.